# SSH Connection Permission Denied (publickey)

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, login

I am being blocked from connecting to linode using my root and using my user. I have read all the other threads and none of the solutions are working for me. While I was connect to ssh before, I blocked root login for safety reasons and I created a user with ssh key login and no password login allowed. It was working fine for a while, but now I am getting Permission denied when trying to connect to root or to my user.

Comment: I have checked all the other threads as well, but none of the solutions worked for me.

Comment: @sara-abu-hattab: Can you please edit your post to include the ssh debug reply that you get... removing any personally identifying information, but leaving the errors?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your ssh agent is stopped, try the following:

```bsh
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add /path/to/your/key
```

---

`No more authentication methods to try. root@192.168.1.10: Permission denied (publickey).`

Seems that the `ssh-agent` does not have the correct ssh keys for authenticate the connection.

Comment: When I do eval $(ssh-agent) it says "Agent pid 52"

Comment: I do not think this is the problem

Comment: Of course, this means that the ssh agent is started. Try to connect after restarting the ssh-agent

Comment: On the client or server? I ran it on both boxes and both showed a pid. I ran ssh-add with no parameters on the server. That didn't fix the problem.

Comment: restarted ssh-agent. eval now shows different pids on the 2 machines. ssh failed again with same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I have read DOZENS of the postings I found by searching with the string in the subject above and none helps.

I am missing something - probably elementary - and need another/many pair of eyes to see what that is.

So here's what I did. I upgraded my development desktop from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04 but, wisely, have not upgraded my "production" desktop from 18.04 yet and won't do so until all my applications work properly.

ssh seemed OK on the 20.04 "client" until I started to tweak it to get Mysql Workbench to connect to the server.

I now keep on getting the error message in the subject.

Here is the output of the command
ssh -i  -vvv server_ip

`OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "192.168.1.10" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.10 [192.168.1.10] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.10:22 as 'root'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.1.10
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:ihT4T/0uZlh6ujuMQIWNoKWdf8zONBap92BeMbstNtg
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.1.10
debug1: Host '192.168.1.10' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (0x55ee3b0d8ad0), explicit
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55ee3b0d7d30)
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 53
debug3: input_userauth_banner
Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS \n \l

debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:sOPLHvZ4E2sxXV2Cvs2/HqGH5Rkx/Wx2KdSsNULofl8 /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:sOPLHvZ4E2sxXV2Cvs2/HqGH5Rkx/Wx2KdSsNULofl8 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
root@192.168.1.10: Permission denied (publickey).`

Where is it getting the public key SHA256:sOPLHvZ4E... from? I can find no such string in any of the id_rsa* files, nor the authorized_keys on the server.

Here's what I have done:
1. apt-get remove ssh
2. apt-get purge ssh
both on client, then reinstalled
3. apt-get install openssh-client

On the server 
apt-get remove ssh 
apt-get remove openssh-server
apt-get purge ssh
apt-get purge openssh-server

My permissions on both server and client are 700 for /root/.ssh directories, 644 for id_rsa.pub and 600 for id_rsa

I ran ssh-keygen on client and copied the contents of id_rsa.pub to authorized_keys on the server.
 In /etc/ssh/ssh_config on both machines I have 
`PasswordAuthentication no
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
On the client in /etc/ssh/sshd_config I have
`PubkeyAuthentication yes
RSAAuthentication    yes
PasswordAuthentication no`
but I also have the following lines commented out (is this OK?)
`#AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

## AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

## AuthorizedKeysCommand none

## AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody`

and
`X11Forwarding no
MaxStartups 2:30:10
AllowUsers  <me> root`

On the server:
In ssh_config:
`PasswordAuthentication no
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa ------> should this be authorized_keys???`
In sshd_config:
`LogLevel VERBOSE
LoginGraceTime 30
PermitRootLogin yes
RSAAuthentication    yes

## AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

PasswordAuthentication no
AllowTcpForwarding no
MaxStartups 2:30:10`

The /var/log/auth.log has nothing spectacular in it, that catches my eye.

So, can any of your eyes catch the cause of the error?

Thanks in advance.

May 5, 2020

I solved this problem - amazingly simple - by installing openssh-server on the local client!!!!

Comment: Oh! I ran the following command to enable mysql workbench to connect to the server - it didn't: snap connect mysql-workbench-community:ssh-keys